# do_action in conditional

Tags: plugins, conditional-content

I'm using the "inbox-status" plugin.
I can use this to display unread emails.

```
<?php do_action( 'inbox_status_count', 'inbox-unread' ); ?>
```

I want to use this code in a conditional. Only the number of emails shown if more than one.

```
if ( 0 < did_action( 'inbox_status_count', 'inbox-unread' ) )
    echo "<span class='new badge'>";
    echo do_action( 'inbox_status_count', 'inbox-unread' );
    echo "</span>";
```

Why don't work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that `did_action` only takes **one** input argument: *the name of the action hook*.

The scope of your `if` sentence is also unclear.

I don't think you want to use `did_action` at all here, it doesn't give you the number of emails.

You can try the following instead:

```
if ( $unread = do_shortcode( '[input-unread]' ) )
    printf( "<span class='new badge'>%s</span>", $unread );
```

or skip the expensive `do_shortcode` parsing by using the shortcode callback directly:

```
if( 
       class_exists( 'IS_Inbox_Status' ) 
    && $unread = IS_Inbox_Status::get_instance()->get_count( 'inbox-unread' )
)   
    printf( "<span class='new badge'>%s</span>", $unread );
```

Note that this is untested.

Comment: Thanks, both work. `if ( $unread = do_shortcode("[inbox-unread]") )`